# Impossible to start spice manager as no service (Robospice)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, robospice

When I am trying to run Robospice Retrofit sample code I got this Error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to start SpiceManager as no service of class : com.example.dinesh.basicfragments.SampleRetrofitService is registered in AndroidManifest.xml file !

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: One of my app's user has the same error when others don't have ! I have added the service in Manifest, this is not the problem... The user is running Andrid 4.1 on Samsung Galaxy S2, can it be in relation with his phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your service to AndroidMAnifest file like this:

```
<service
        android:name=".SampleRetrofitService"
        android:exported="false" />
```